# Angular Service method is called twice?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple service:

```
angular.module('sf').factory 'sfStatic2',  ->
  {
    doSomething: ->
      console.log('called-x')
      43
  }

angular.module('sf').controller 'UserRegisterCtrl', ($scope,sfStatic2) ->
  $scope.timezoneX = sfStatic2.doSomething()
```

In the console I see two times 'called-x', do you know why is this happening ? I am using angular 1.3.15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be occuring due to controller being called two times.
Make sure you are writing controller only once.
write either in ng-controller or  in your config route.

route config (usually, app.js):

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/',
               { 
                   templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
                   //Remove controller from here
               });
}]);
home.html

 <!-- Add the ng-controller in your view -->
    <div ng-controller="MyItemsController">
        <!-- Your stuff -->
    </div>
```